# Summary of Dataset using lapply

Tags: r, lapply, summarization

This is a novice question, however, I am finding it very difficult to understand how to use lapply correctly, especially when the ID used is not numeric.

There are possibly better methods to trying to find the summary I have in mind, but for now, I'm trying to use lapply. Essentially, I have a large df with 17 columns. Two of the column are ID and Date. Not all IDs have a recorded value in a given column name. What I am interested in is finding the total number of rows available for each column, and the number of unique IDs that exist for that column. I have a dput example that makes things clearer. For example, Var8 has only 6 rows of data available, as a result it has 6 unique IDs. Also, Var15 has 20 rows and 12 unique IDs. But I want to know this for all Var15. I can do this manually using

```
Var8=df[!(is.na(df$Var8)),]
length(df$ID)
length(unique(df$ID)) 
remove(Var8)
```

But trying to automate:

```
lapply(COL.NAMES, function(x){
       temp=df[!(is.na(df$paste(x))),]
       rows=length(temp$ID)
       num_comp=length(unique(temp$ID)) 
       return(rows)
       return(num_comp)
       remove(temp)
})
```

leaves me with an error: attempt to apply non-function.

```
COL.NAMES<-c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4","Var5","Var6","Var7","Var8","Var9","Var10","Var11","Var12","Var13","Var14","Var15")


structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("Comp1", 
"Comp10", "Comp11", "Comp12", "Comp2", "Comp3", "Comp4", "Comp5", 
"Comp6", "Comp7", "Comp8", "Comp9"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0/1/2014", "0/1/2015"), class = "factor"), 
    Var1 = c(0.57, 0.34, 0.38, 0.93, 0.54, 0.17, 0.08, 0.28, 
    0.99, 1, 0.61, 0.73, 0.15, 0.09, 0.64, 0.3, 0.12, 0.79, 0.79, 
    0.15), Var2 = c(0.7, 0.77, 0.93, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.46, 0.26), Var3 = c(0.65, 
    0.7, 0.83, 0.7, 0.43, 0.81, 0.21, 0.44, 0.25, 0.77, 0.24, 
    0.29, 0.87, 0.42, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.79), Var4 = c(1, 0.7, 
    0.69, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.61, 0.89, 0.45, 0.02, 0.97, 
    0.33, 0.34, 0.81, 0.99, 0.35, 0.48, 0.33), Var5 = c(0.47, 
    0.95, 0.38, 0.69, 0.84, 0.21, 0.62, 0.59, 0.45, 0.63, 0.18, 
    0.49, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.17, 0.15, 0.6, 0.44), Var6 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.24, 0.07, 0.75, 0.24, 0.82, 0.14, 0.86, 0.63, 
    0.82, 0.92, 0.55, 0.22, 0.87, 0.69, 0.64, 0.73), Var7 = c(0.2, 
    0.11, 0.82, 0.31, 0.97, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.83, 0.84, 0.81, 
    0.72, 0.36, 0.09, 0.15, 0.46, 0.79, 0.75, 0.39), Var8 = c(0.28, 
    0.55, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.56, 0.89, 0.92, 0.46, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Var9 = c(0.11, 0.36, 1, 0.44, 
    0.53, 0.6, 0.24, 0.56, 0.6, 0.55, 0.55, 0.05, 0.77, 0.9, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.4, 0.33), Var10 = c(0.74, 0.13, 0.09, 0.61, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.27, 0.71, 0.56, 0.3, 0.36, 0.44, 0.78, 
    0.9, 0.46, 0.49, 0.87, 0.36), Var11 = c(0.58, 0.99, 0.07, 
    0.83, 0.45, 0.07, 0.16, 0.43, 0.34, 0.31, 0.06, 0.67, 0.02, 
    0.52, 0.19, 0.49, 0.31, 0.02, 0.62, 0.21), Var12 = c(0.93, 
    0.26, 0.77, 0.8, 0.67, 0.83, 0.12, 0.39, 0.78, 0.75, 0.44, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.42, 0.49, 0.06, 0.8, 0.54), Var13 = c(0.44, 
    0.75, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.58, 0.3, 0.47, 0.88, 0.36, 0.21, 
    0.87, 0.33, 0.12, 0.31, 0.95, 0.59, 0.18, 0.43), Var14 = c(0.55, 
    0.03, 0.37, 0.66, NA, 0.91, 0.78, 0.84, 0.96, 0.34, 0.25, 
    0.92, 0.71, 0.41, 0.23, 0.54, 0.8, 0.87, 0.3, 0.37), Var15 = c(0.71, 
    0.66, 0.01, 0.7, 0.4, 0.04, 0.3, 1, 0.59, 0.69, 0.88, 0.28, 
    0.44, 0.51, 0.2, 0.17, 0.6, 0.11, 0.85, 0.04)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date", "Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7", 
"Var8", "Var9", "Var10", "Var11", "Var12", "Var13", "Var14", 
"Var15"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: The answer below by Adam Quek is what you need, but the reason why you are getting the error message is because you have two return statements in your function. You can return a list instead or a vector of the two values. You also don't need the remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood correctly but this could be your solution .
x is your dataframe

```
try1 <-  function(df){
  temp <- sum(!is.na(df)) ## no of non na entries 
  temp2 <- length(unique(df)) # length unique entries `
  temp <- list("x"=temp,"y"=temp2)
  temp

}

> lapply(x,try1)
```

Here is a data.table soln

```
library(data.table)
dd <- as.data.table(x)

COL.NAMES<-c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4","Var5","Var6","Var7","Var8","Var9","Var10","Var11","Var12","Var13","Var14","Var15")

dd[,lapply(.SD, try1),.SDcols=COL.NAMES]
```

Comment: Least complicated answer; I fully understand what you are doing here and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would advise getting yourself familiar with data wrangling using dplyr. The magrittr pipes `%>%` implemented will help you with understanding the usage of apply.

Here's how I would change your function:

```
library(dplyr)
tmp<-lapply(COL.NAMES, function(x) df[,c("ID", x)] %>% na.omit) # loop and extract 15 data.frames, each with 2 columns; remove rows with missing value
rows <- sapply(tmp, nrow) 
num_comp <- lapply(tmp, '[[', "ID") %>% lapply(., unique) %>% sapply(., length) #extract only ID column from list of 15 data.frame; loop across each vector to retain unique values; count length of vector.
```

Comment: You're not using dplyr here, except for the `%>%` which originates from `magrittr` as you know

Comment: I appreciate this answer and will definitely look into the %>% functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be,

```
df1 <- data.frame(n_rows = colSums(!is.na(df[,-(1:2)]), na.rm = TRUE), 
                  unique_IDs = sapply(df[,-2], function(i) length(unique(df$ID[!is.na(i)])))[-1])
head(df1)
#     n_rows unique_IDs
#Var1     20         12
#Var2      5          5
#Var3     16         12
#Var4     16         12
#Var5     16         12
#Var6     16         12
```

Answer (score 1):

However, I didn't use lapply,this solution does work

```
find.uniques<- function(df){
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){   
    uniques<- data.frame()
    uniques[i,1]<- length(!is.na(unique(df[,i])))
    uniques[i,2]<- length(which(!is.na(unique(df[,i]))))
 }
return(uniques)
}
```

Result is a `data.frame` with V1 as how many rows are available, V2 how many IDs there are for each column. 
You can also `return(as.data.frame(t(uniques)))` to change the rows to columns to see what is available for each column.